# Trying to get the current time but it gives me the wrong time SWIFT 5

Tags: swift, date, swift5

I'm trying to get the current date. Current Date and time is `2019-12-16 05:12:59` but I get `2019-12-16 10:12:59.`

```html
let dateAdded = itemDict["time"] as! String
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let currentTime = df.date(from: dateAdded)
let dateTime = currentTime!.addingTimeInterval(60.0 * 60.0)
let currentDate = Date()
```

Comment: You need to set timezone too.

Comment: What is the string you are converting from? (In full) and what time one are you in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date().toCurrentTimezone()

extension Date {
    func toCurrentTimezone() -> Date {
        let timeZoneDifference = 
        TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
        return self.addingTimeInterval(timeZoneDifference)
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not compile. Where does the `toCurrentTimezone` method come from?

Comment: @MartinR have you added the extension?

Answer (score 0):

To get the current time without a format you can simply just add this:

```
let currentDateTime = Date()
print(currentDateTime)
```

But if you would like to retrieve a "string" and convert it into a date you can do:

```
let dateAdded = itemDict["time"] as! String
//Convert string to date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAdded!)
```

If you're still getting wrong time, you should add timezone. In that case the code will be something like this:

```
let dateAdded = itemDict["time"] as! String
//Convert string to date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAdded!)
```

If you're using uppercase "HH" that means you're using the 24h clock. Otherwise use small case "hh".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your local time zone in date formator.

```
//Get local time Zone
var localTimeZoneIdentifier: String { return TimeZone.current.identifier }
print("local Time zone: " + localTimeZoneIdentifier)

let inputdateString: String = "2019-12-16 05:12:59"
let dateFormatter  = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localTimeZoneIdentifier)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let inputDate = dateFormatter.date(from: inputdateString )!
print("Output date: \(String(describing: inputDate))")
```

**out put:-**

```
local Time zone:-Asia/Kolkata
Output date: 2019-12-15 23:42:59 +0000
```